# How to take screenshot of device camera with the CCLayer on it

Tags: iphone, cocos2d-iphone, uiimagepickercontroller, augmented-reality, cclayer

I have set up a camera and I managed to add the Cocos2d Layer above the camera, Now I want to take a screenshot of the total view i.e the camera and with the image on the layer above the camera.

Since my CCLayer is made transparent the camera can be seen through.

Any ideas/links/details on how to do this.. ?

Thanks in advance for your time :)

**EDIT:** THIS IS MY CODE FOR THE SCREENSHOT

```
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext([CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.superview.frame.size);
    [[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.superview.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage * image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    CGRect rect;
    rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320);
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([image CGImage],[CCDirector sharedDirector].openGLView.superview.frame);
    UIImage * img =[UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    CGImageRelease(imageRef);
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, nil, nil, nil);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size); 
 [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()]; 
 UIImage *viewImage=UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext(); 
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

//It will give you the uiimage

Comment: Since I am using Cocos2d ..! Self.view.layer wont work ..!
How to use this code in Cocos2d.. ?I tried some work around, But all I get is Black/White screen as a screeshot.

Comment: I tried that too, But still I get just black screen as a screenShot. 
Also please have a look at my EDIT in question, I have put some code that I am using for the SCreenShot.

Comment: I used them, I used AVFoundation, QuartzCore and CoreGraphics as well..!

Comment: //use this UIGraphicsEndImageContext(); u use UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

Comment: Still a black screen :( 
Anything wrong the way I am using this code ?

Comment: I do get it it NSlog, it shows that some memory is allocated, But the screenShot gives black screen.

Comment: check with uiimageview

UIImageView *invertedImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:viewImage];
    [invertedImage setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480)];

Comment: Thanks a lot..!! But its for the UIKit, It cant be used in Cocos2d. Iam looking for Cocos2d ..! Using it may affect the performance.

Answer (score 0):

To all those who are looking for the same thing ..! I have got it working using AVFoundation framework. 
[This is one nice tutorial on how to achieve this :)](http://invasivecode.tumblr.com/post/18445861158/a-very-cool-custom-video-camera-with)